# My pygame isn't working but everything seems fine

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Everything seems fine but my computer found that i have invalid syntax and it marks colon(:). 
code:

```
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width: # <- here he marks this colon
        man.x = man.x + man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False
```

**Full code:**

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

cl = pygame.time.Clock()

lefty = [pygame.image.load('Game/L1.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L2.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L3.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L4.png'),pygame.image.load('Game\L5.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L6.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L7.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L8.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/L9.png')]
righty = [pygame.image.load('Game/R1.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R2.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R3.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R4.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R5.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R6.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R7.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R8.png'),pygame.image.load('Game/R9.png')]
gr = pygame.image.load('Game/bg.jpg')
st = pygame.image.load('Game/standing.png')

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,480))
name = pygame.display.set_caption("photo game")

class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.jump=False
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount= 0
        self.standing = True

    def draw(self,win):
        if self.walkCount+1>=27:
            self.walkCount=0
        if not(self.standing):
            if self.left:
                win.blit(lefty[self.walkCount//3],(self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount +=1
            elif self.right:
                win.blit(righty[self.walkCount//3],(self.x,self.y))
                self.walkCount +=1
        else:
            if self.right:
                win.blit(righty[0], (self.x, self.y))
            else:
                win.blit(lefty[0], (self.x, self.y))

class projectiles(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,radius,color,facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(win, self):
        pygame.draw.radius(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius, self.facing)

def redrawchar():
    win.blit(gr,(0,0))
    man.draw(win)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

man = player(50, 420, 62, 62)
while True:
    cl.tick(27)
    bullets = []

    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break

    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:bullet.x += bullet.vel
        else: bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_c]:
        if man.right:
            facing=1
        else:
            facing = -1
        if len(bullets) < 5:
            bullets.append(projectiles((round(man.x + man.weight //2)), (round(man.y + man.height //2)), 6, (0,0,0), facing)

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width: #here is that error
        man.x = man.x + man.vel
        man.right = True
        man.left = False
        man.standing = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel-5-5:
        man.x-=man.vel
        man.left = True
        man.right = False
        man.standing = False

    else:
        man.standing = True
        man.walkCount=0
    if not(man.jump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            man.jump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount=0
    else:
        if man.jumpCount>=-10:
            man.y -= (man.jumpCount*abs(man.jumpCount)) *0.5
            man.jumpCount -=1
        else:
            man.jumpCount = 10
            man.jump = False

    redrawchar()
pygame.quit()
```

I tryed to put 500 - man.width in brackets like (500 - man.width): but it's not working.

Can someone please help.

I am working in py 3.7 and everything is ok and seems to be right. However why does my computer not like that colon(:) for some reason?

Does anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is not caused by the line:

> ```py
> if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width:
> ```

This  line is syntactically correct. It is the line before that line, which causes the error:

> ```py
> if len(bullets) < 5:
>    bullets.append(projectiles((round(man.x + man.weight //2)), (round(man.y + man.height //2)), 6, (0,0,0), facing)
> ```

At the end of the call to `bullets.append` is missing the closing bracket `)`. This causes the syntax error in the next line, because the subsequent tokens are unexpected.